# Soma acumulado por linhas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Boa tarde colegas
Gostaria de uma ajuda. No código abaixo eu gero uma coluna nova (acumulado) usando o cumsum. O resultado é uma soma acumulado para cada linha. 
POrém eu preciso trazer o acumulado por linhas para cada critério da coluna cor. 
Eu testei usando o itertuplas, com if's, porém ficou muito muito lento para rodar milhões de linhas.  POr gentileza, podem me ajudar com isso.

Segue o código:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cor': ['azul', 'preto', 'amarelo', 'azul', 'preto', 'amarelo', 'preto', 'azul', 'amarelo', 'azul', 'amarelo'],
                   'preco': [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,1]})

df2 = df.preco

df['acumulado'] = df2.cumsum()

df

##################################
Resultado: 
    cor   preco acumulado
0   azul    1   1
1   preto   1   2
2   amarelo 1   3
3   azul    2   5
4   preto   3   8
5   amarelo 4   12
6   preto   5   17
7   azul    3   20
8   amarelo 2   22
9   azul    4   26
10  amarelo 1   27
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ter o resuntado que você quer tem que chamar o `cumsum()` junto com uma função `groupby()`

A função `groupby()` realiza um agrupamentos de acordo com as colunas que você escolher e permite realizar operações como média, soma e entre outras, nesse caso utilizei a `cumsum()`

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cor': ['azul', 'preto', 'amarelo', 'azul', 'preto', 'amarelo', 'preto', 'azul', 'amarelo', 'azul', 'amarelo'],
                   'preco': [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,1]})

df2 = df.preco

df['acumulado'] = df.groupby(['cor']).cumsum()

##Essas operações são feitas para melhorar o vizual do Data Frame
## 1 - Ordeno pela coluna cor e reseto os index do Data Frama
df = df.sort_values(['cor']).reset_index()

## 2 - Drop na coluna Index antiga
df = df.drop(['index'],axis=1)

##Imprime o Data Frame
print(df)

##Resultado do Data Frame Esperado
#############
        cor  preco  acumulado
0   amarelo      1     1
1   amarelo      4     5
2   amarelo      2     7
3   amarelo      1     8
4      azul      1     1
5      azul      2     3
6      azul      3     6
7      azul      4    10
8     preto      1     1
9     preto      3     4
10    preto      5     9
```

Para maiores informações há esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum) no SO com a mesma dúvida.

[Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) da doc do `groupby()`

Comment: Nossa , ficou excelente. Muito muito obrigado!!!!